How to find a name with conditions ending with some strings and divide them
I have these lists:
list1 = [
    {'itemid': '264', 'name': 'Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14): Bits sent', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
    {'itemid': '215', 'name': 'Interface Te1/50("Port1:CL-PO-G22-23"): Bits received', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
    {'itemid': '425', 'name': 'Interface Gi1/46(no description): Bits sent', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
    {'itemid': '521', 'name': 'Interface Te1/50("Port1:CL-PO-G22-23"): Bits sent', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
    {'itemid': '310', 'name': 'Interface Gi1/46(no description): Bits received', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
    {'itemid': '123', 'name': 'Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14): Bits received', 'some_other_keys': 'some_more_values'},
]
list2 = [
    {'itemid': '264', 'clock': '1724146566', 'value': '6246880', 'ns': '120003316'},
    {'itemid': '264', 'clock': '1724146746', 'value': '6134912', 'ns': '113448784'},
    {'itemid': '215', 'clock': '1724144406', 'value': '5786832', 'ns': '157177073'},
    {'itemid': '215', 'clock': '1724144766', 'value': '5968784', 'ns': '760851309'},
    {'itemid': '425', 'clock': '1724148366', 'value': '6590424', 'ns': '403316048'},
    {'itemid': '425', 'clock': '1724148726', 'value': '6549984', 'ns': '484278803'},
    {'itemid': '521', 'clock': '1724148906', 'value': '6346488', 'ns': '306999249'},
    {'itemid': '521', 'clock': '1724147106', 'value': '6139008', 'ns': '459391602'},
    {'itemid': '310', 'clock': '1724147286', 'value': '6000208', 'ns': '826776455'},
    {'itemid': '310', 'clock': '1724147466', 'value': '6784960', 'ns': '152620809'},
    {'itemid': '123', 'clock': '1724147826', 'value': '6865272', 'ns': '70247389'},
    {'itemid': '123', 'clock': '1724148186', 'value': '6544328', 'ns': '610791670'},
]

Now I'm going to do this:
First, store the sum and average of each itemid in list2 based on the value (for example, for itemid 264, sum all its values then divide by the len() function):
Second, find each two itemids in the list1 and see if their names match:
Third, divide values which have received by sent.
I add all values of the same itemid like this:
from collections import defaultdict
new_list = defaultdict(list)
for entry in list2:
    if int(entry['value']) > 0:
        new_list[int(entry['itemid'])].append(int(entry['value']))

# >>> new_list
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {264: [6246880, 6134912], 215: [5786832, 5968784], 425: [6590424, 6549984], 521: [6346488, 6139008], 310: [6000208, 6784960], 123: [6865272, 6544328]})

Now I should find if id 264's name (name.split(': Bits')[0] in fact) in list1 matches with which id, then divide .endswith('Bits received') / .endswith('Bits sent').
Let's suppose this:

id 264's name is Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14) and another id with this name is 123. Now we divide the sum all values having id 123 (because it's received) by the sum all values having id 264 (because it's sent).

Should be like this:
    [
        {'name': 'Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14)', 'received': 13409600, 'sent': 12381792, 'ratio': 1.0830096322083265} # ( (6865272 + 6544328) / (6246880 + 6134912) )
    ]

With this code, I can sum and average each itemid (but that's not what I'm going to do):
import datetime
for x in new_list:
    print(f"Item ID: {x}, Ratio: {float(str(sum(new_list[x]) / len(new_list[x]) / 1000 / 1000)[:3])}")

Current output:
Item ID: 264, Ratio: 6.1
Item ID: 215, Ratio: 5.8
Item ID: 425, Ratio: 6.5
Item ID: 521, Ratio: 6.2
Item ID: 310, Ratio: 6.3
Item ID: 123, Ratio: 6.7

Fully expected output:
output = [
    {'name': 'Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14)', 'received': 13409600, 'sent': 12381792, 'ratio': 1.0830096322083265}, # ( (6865272 + 6544328) / (6246880 + 6134912) )
    {'name': 'Interface Te1/50("Port1:CL-PO-G22-23")', 'received': 11755616, 'sent': 12485496, 'ratio': 0.941541769746272}, # ( (5786832 + 5968784) / (6346488 + 6139008) )
    {'name': 'Interface Gi1/46(no description)', 'received': 12785168, 'sent': 13140408, 'ratio': 0.9729658318067446}, # ( (6000208 + 6784960) / (6590424 + 6549984) )
]

Would you please help me how to reach it?

In order to get the output like this,
[{'name': 'Interface Gi1/17(Port1:TP TPIA-CL03-017-G15-14)', 'received': 13409600, 'sent': 12381792, 'ratio': 1.0830096322083265}, {'name': 'Interface Te1/50("Port1:CL-PO-G22-23")', 'received': 11755616, 'sent': 12485496, 'ratio': 0.941541769746272}, {'name': 'Interface Gi1/46(no description)', 'received': 12785168, 'sent': 13140408, 'ratio': 0.9729658318067446}]

you have to map to the output after calculation with ratio
for key, values in matches.items():
    output.append({
        'name': key,
        'received': received,
        'sent': sent,
        'ratio': ratio
    })

Fully updated code
